# GUI isn't showing up after running python code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tkinter

I'm building an Image to PDF converter app using python. When I run the code in the terminal the UI doesn't appear. Here is the code:

```
`import tkinter as tk
 from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
 import os

 class ImageToPdfConverter:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.image_paths = []
        self.output_pdf_name = tk.StringVar()
        self.selected_image_listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)

        self.initialize_ui()

    def initialize_ui(self):
        title_label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "Image to PDF Converter", font=("Helvetica", 16,
        "bold"))
        title_label.pack(pady=10)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Image to PDF")
    root.geometry("400x600")
    root.mainloop()

    if __name__== "__main__":
        main()`
```

When I click "Run Python File in Terminal", it runs however the UI does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

The indentation of the `main` function at the end of the code is incorrect and should be changed to the following

```py
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Image to PDF")
    root.geometry("400x600")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```